# First Setting up Phonegap on MacBook

Tags: macos, cordova, mobile

I've bought my first ever MacBook having never used a Mac before and need to know how to set up pretty much the same tools or learn whatever the Mac version of these tools are, heres a guide I wrote for getting started with Phonegap on Windows, if I follow it as close as I can, will everything work?

> • Download/ Install Node.JS
>
> • Download/ Install GIT for windows
>
> • Download/ Install Phonegap by opening NODE.JS command line and
>   typing: npm install -g phonegap
>
> • Download/ Install Apache 2.4
>
> • Download/ Install Apache Ant
>
> • Add Variable name: ANT_HOME with filepath to User/ System variables
>   (e.g. C:\apache-ant-1.9.4  )
>
> • Add %ANT_HOME%/bin to PATH under user variables
>
> • Download/ Install JRE ( select applicable version number (if in
>   doubt then most recent))
>
> • Download/ Install JDK (Select applicable version number (if in doubt
>   then most recent))
>
> • Add Variable name: JAVA_HOME with filepath to User/ System variables
>   (e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60  )
>
> • Add %JAVA_HOME%/bin to PATH under user variables
>
> • Download / Extract Android SDK ( select "download for other
>   platforms" and select version to avoid downloading their bundle)
>
> • Add Android SDK Tools folder eg: C:\android-sdk-windows\tools to the
>   PATH variable
>
> • Add Android SDK Platform tools eg:
>   C:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools to the PATH variable

Thankyou in advance for your help!

Lewis

Comment: JDK & JRE are already installed on MacOSX by default. 

To setup phonegap accordingly you have to install node.js & git.
I also suggest to install homebrew, a console package manager for macosx which makes things a lot easier. You can run `brew install git`  to install git and so on.
http://brew.sh/

Once you installed phonegap you can create a new phonegap project.
Phonegap will automatically download the required SDKs for the target OS. 

Also install XCode (free from AppStore). If you follow the instructions on the developer websites you shouldn't have too much of a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mac is build on a unix platform. 
This means it comes with a lot of tools that are Linux like.
To install application on the mac you can use brew ( http://www.brew.sh ). Brew is a package management system similar to the ones from linux world (yum for RedHat or apt-get for Ubuntu).

To install brew run this command in the Terminal:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

After you have brew installed on your machine, you can add your packages with:

```
brew install [packagename]
```

**Your installation flow would look like this:**

```
brew install node
brew install git
npm install -g phonegap
```

For apache and ant check the existing answers on stackoverflow.

To add environment variable on mac use the Terminal and edit your “.profile” or “.bash_profile”. There are detailed answear on stackoverflow regarding this subject.

Java will need to be installed from the Oracle website (download the .dmg file and execute it)

```
brew install android-sdk
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for the fast reply, this was very enlightening!